# SQL trigger DATEPART is not declared

Tags: sql, oracle, date, database-trigger, datepart

I am trying to create a trigger that prompts an error message if the current time is between 10pm and 6am. This is the code I wrote:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER horarioModificar 
BEFORE UPDATE ON employees
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   horaActual NUMBER:= DATEPART(hour, SYSDATETIME());
BEGIN 
    IF  horaActual < 6 OR horaActual > 22 THEN
        raise_application_error(-20250,'No se puede realizar ningún cambio entre las 22:00 y las 6:00');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

I got an error saying that DATEPART needs to be declared (error code  PLS-00201). Does anybody know what's wrong with my code?

Comment: It would help if you added a tag for your specific rdbms (e.g. [tag:mysql] or [tag:sql-server]). Datetime functionality varies between these systems.

Comment: I added the `oracle` tag, since error code `PLS-00201` indicates that this is the database that you are running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you are getting (PLS-00201) indicates that you are running Oracle.

Here is a new version of the trigger code that would run on Oracle:

```
create or replace trigger horariomodificar 
before update on employees 
for each row 
begin 
    if not extract(hour from systimestamp) between 6 and 22 
        then raise_application_error(
            -20250,
            'no se puede realizar ningún cambio entre las 22:00 y las 6:00'
        ); 
    end if; 
end; 
/
```

Notable points:

- `datepart()` does not exist in Oracle (this is a SQL Server function); you can use `extract(hour from systimestamp)` to get the current hour
- you don't really need to use a variable, so I removed that
- this code actually prevents changes between *23h* and 6h, not between *22h* and 6h; otherwise, you want: `if not extract(hour from systimestamp) not between 6 and and 21`